# How to Insert HTML tags into string by raw string indices in Python?

Tags: python

I want to highlight some part of my text by indices and put it into HTML. The problem is that as I insert a tag the indices will change. I tried to get the difference between the original text and the formatted but as soon as the indices are not sorted or any of them is overlapping the other the formatting is off.

```
result = {'passive': [(0, 18, 'Mistakes were made', 'passive')],
 'word_repeating': [(270, 275, 'in in', 'word_repeat')],
 'filler_words': [(27, 30, 'uhm', 'fillers'), (929, 932, 'ahm', 'fillers')],
 'long_sentences': [(747, 964, 38, 'sentence_len')]}

formatted = text
START = "<span style='color: red'>"
END = "</span>"

for key in result.keys():
  for el in result[key]:
    diff = len(formatted) - len(text)
    start = el[0] + diff
    end = el[1] + diff
    formatted = formatted[:start] + START + formatted[start:end] + END + formatted[end:]
```